# Spring Boot app packaged as WAR deployed on Jetty 9.2

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jetty

I have created a Spring Boot application. It runs properly in standalone mode. My next step is to produce a WAR file that can be loaded by an embedded Jetty Server instance (version 9.2).

I managed to generate a WAR file. However, by default Spring Boot annotations are not interpreted and Spring Boot itself is not loading (i.e. when I open the URL associated to the app, WAR files are listed).

One manner I found to make Spring Boot to start consists in adding a *web.xml* file in *WEB-INF* with an application context that enables *component-scan*. This way, Spring Boot is loaded by the embedded Jetty server. However, it looks like some application properties (from *META-INFO/application.properties* file) are not evaluated: for instance `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` has no effect and `create-drop` is used instead.

I was able to reconfigure a few beans to make some application properties work but not the last one related to hibernate. It looks like all Spring auto configurations are not enabled.

Is there a mean to make a Spring boot application packaged as a WAR deployed on Jetty without *web.xml* or at least with a *generic* configuration that enables all Spring auto configurations?

Below is the code related to the creation of the embedded Jetty server:

```
Server server = createHttpServer(properties, restPort, httpsEnabled);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
addWarsToHandlerList(handlerList);
server.setHandler(handlerList);
server.start();
```

The method `addWarsToHandlerList` is simply calling the following method for all WAR archives to deploy on the application server:

```
private static void addWarFile(HandlerList handlerList, File file) {
    String contextPath = "/" + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());
    WebAppContext webApp = createWebAppContext(contextPath);
    webApp.setWar(file.getAbsolutePath());
    handlerList.addHandler(webApp);
    logger.debug("Deploying " + contextPath + " using war file " + file);
}
```

Hereafter, the Web configuration. First my *web.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and the *applicationContext.xml* file used by the previous one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>

    <bean id="appConfigProperties"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any comment, suggestion, etc. are welcome.

Comment: So you are using an embedded Jetty container in one of your Spring Boot apps to deploy more external WAR files? Or did i understand this wrong? Right now it looks to me, that you work around Spring Boot in several ways which also causes Spring Boot to not function properly. E.g. you don't need a web.xml with Spring Boot, instead you use the SpringBootServletInitializer.

Comment: No, I think my explanations were not clear enough. I have an application running a Jetty embedded server on a machine _A_. On another machine _B_, I have developed a Spring Boot application. What I try to achieve is to package the Spring Boot application as a WAR that can be deployed on the application server that runs on machine _A_, with all Spring Boot features that work.

Comment: And what application server runs on machine A?

Comment: Jetty 9.2 embedded server running on machine _A_ is my application server.

Comment: Well if it's an embedded server, i wouldn't call it an application server, since it still runs within another application. Is this application, where this embedded server is running, also a Spring Boot application?

Comment: Ok, sorry for using the wrong term. No, this application is not a Spring Boot application. It does some stuff and starts the Jetty embedded instance using the code I put in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring auto-configurations were loaded but `application.properties` file was not. A solution was to use @PropertySource with my application class:

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
}`